# SQL - how to count unique combination of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to count the number of unique value in a table.  I know to count the number of unique folderIDs I do:

```
select count(folderid) from folder
```

but I want the count of the number of unique combination of folderid and userid in the folder table.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `select count(distinct folder) from folder`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct folderid, userid from folder
)
```

Comment: Duh, hadn't seen this is Oracle... on MSSQL you'd need it... my bad, will remove comment again =(

Answer (score 13):

```
select count(*) from (
    select folderId, userId
    from folder
    group by folderId, userId
) t
```

Comment: I tried the other solutions provided in the answers, but in my case only this works. The significant difference I can see is the presence of a 't' at then end. Can some one explain this part?

Comment: @jazaman, `t`  is a sub-query alias, I've added `as` keyword for clarification.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `AS` for a table alias.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right. My mistake, since ~4 years only SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the count of unique folderid and userid combinations:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               folderid,
               userid
          FROM folder
);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try to group the select statement with folder id

eg.

i have a table

> folderid userid
>
> 1         11
>
> 1         11
>
> 2         12
>
> 2         12
>
> 3         13
>
> 3         13

Query is

```
select count(folderid) from testtable group by folderid, userid
```

Comment: For your sample data, this query will return 3 rows, all with the value 2, which is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT super_group_account_id,

       sub_group_account_id,

       **Concat**(super_group_account_id, ' ', sub_group_account_id),

       *Count*(**Concat**(super_group_account_id, ' ', sub_group_account_id))

FROM   super_sub_group_mapping

GROUP  BY **Concat**(super_group_account_id, ' ', sub_group_account_id)

HAVING *Count*(**Concat**(super_group_account_id, ' ', sub_group_account_id)) > 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select APPRSL_ID,SECTION_ID, count(APPRSL_ID||SECTION_ID)
from REMARKSBYEACHSECTION 
group by APPRSL_ID,SECTION_ID
having count(APPRSL_ID||SECTION_ID)>1 ;
```