# Getting Count Only of Distinct Value Combinations of multiple fields.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Customer') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Customer;

CREATE TABLE #Customer
(
   CustomerKey    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
  ,CustomerNum    INT NOT NULL
  ,CustomerName   VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
  ,Planet         VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Customer (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet)
VALUES  (1, 'Anakin Skywalker', 'Tatooine')
      , (2, 'Yoda', 'Coruscant')
      , (3, 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'Coruscant')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Tatooine')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Tatooine')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Bespin')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Bespin')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Endor')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Tatooine')
      , (4, 'Luke Skywalker', 'Kashyyyk');
```

Notice that there are a total of 10 records. I know that I can get the list of distinct combinations of CustomerName and PLanet eith either of the following two queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName, Planet FROM #Customer;

SELECT CustomerName, Planet FROM #Customer
GROUP BY CustomerName, Planet;
```

However, what I'd like is a simple way to get just the count of those values, not the values themselves. I'd like a way that's quick to type, but also performant. I know I could load the values into a CTE, Temp Table, Table Variable, or Sub Query, and then count the records. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is "quick to type" a requirement? How often are you writing these queries by hand? Can you tell us what's more important: that the query is efficient, or that the query is "quick to type"?

Comment: I've added a couple of other query variations to [@ypercube's SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8deb/25). You should test those and then *you* can decide which one you like best based on performance and/or the strain on your typing fingers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - how to count unique combination of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519747/sql-how-to-count-unique-combination-of-columns)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work in 2005:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
 ( SELECT 1 AS d
   FROM  Customer
   GROUP BY Customername, Planet
 ) AS t ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8deb/43)**. An index on `(CustomerName, Planet)` would be used, see the query plan (for 2012 version):

[image: Query Plan]

The simplest to think, "get all distinct values in a subquery, then count" , yiields the same identical plan:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
 ( SELECT DISTINCT Customername, Planet
   FROM  Customer
 ) AS t ;
```

And also the one (thanx to @Aaron Bertrand) using ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()` (not sure if it will be efficient in 2005 version, too, but you can test):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
  (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName, Planet 
                ORDER BY CustomerName) 
   FROM Customer) AS x 
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

There are also other ways to write this (one even without subquery, thanx to @Mikael Erksson!) but not as efficient.

Comment: Two more ways to skin the cat in this updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8deb/49).

Answer (score 2):

The subquery/CTE method is the "right" way to do it.

A quick (in terms of typing but not necessarily performance) and dirty way is:

```
select count(distinct customername+'###'+Planet)
from #Customer;
```

The `'###'` is to separate the values so you don't get accidental collisions.

Comment: Terrible performance-wise though. And also you have to be sure that `#` can't naturally appear in your data,

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The OP specifically says not to use a CTE/subquery etc:  "I know I could load the values into a CTE, Temp Table, Table Variable, or Sub Query, and then count the records."  Can you think of another method?

Comment: I realize that. My comment is not just for the OP (who also stated that "performant" - not a word - is a requirement). Your answers says "a quick and dirty way" which might lead people to believe it performs the same as, or maybe even better than, a subquery. You should include a disclaimer that it will actually be slower than the subquery / CTE approaches. *I think the requirement to not use a subquery / CTE is an artificial one anyway.*