# How to count unique rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database table with a lot of columns. I'd like to count the number of fully unique rows. The only thing I could find is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col_name) FROM table;
```

This however would require me listing all the columns and I haven't been able to come up with syntax that will do that for me. I'm guessing the reason for that is that this query would be very low performance? Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - how to count unique combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519747/sql-how-to-count-unique-combination-of-columns)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table)
```

Comment: I got here because I was hoping there is simplier way without using a subquery.

Answer (score 19):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. 
To get a count of the distinct rows by specific column, so that you know what data exists, and how many of that distinct data there are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

A_CODE, COUNT(*) 

FROM MY_ARCHV

GROUP BY A_CODE
```

--This informs me there are 93 unique codes, and how many of each of those codes there are.

Another method

--How to count how many of a type value exists in an oracle table:
`select A_CDE`,  --the value you need to count
`count(*) as numInstances` --how many of each value
`from A_ARCH`  -- the table where it resides
`group by A_CDE` -- sorting method

Either way, you get something that looks like this:

```
A_CODE  Count(*)

1603    32

1600    2

1605    14
```

Comment: SELECT and SELECT DISTINCT mean the same thing here. You are selecting the columns in the GROUP BY and they will always be different.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a count of all distinct rows from a table like this

```
select count(1) as c
from (
    select distinct *
    from tbl
) distinct_tbl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  **col_name**, count(*) FROM **table_name** group by **col_name**
```

Comment: Please note that "code only" answers are discouraged. If at all, at least format it properly!